# AJAX pagination not working properly after new entry

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having a main page "landing.php", here in a div i am calling another page using ajax function "fetch_pages.php". In fetch_pages.php, i am loading data from db as 5 records at a time, when the user reaches the end of page then next 5 records are displayed. Thats working perfectly.

But in landing.php, when i enter a new record and reload the div, then the div content becomes blank, it doesn't show the latest content, after refreshing the full page manually then its again shows all the records. Can't understand whats wrong, kindly help.

landing.php page

```
        <div class="mainsection">
          <div>
             <div class="pull-left postimage"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$ProfilePic ." />"; ?></div>
        <div class="pull-left posttext">
            <div class="postname"><?php echo $Name; ?></div>
            <p><?php echo $UT." - ".$Designation." - ".$Company; ?></p></div>
            <textarea id="posting" name="posting" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Share something here..."></textarea>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="fileUpload btn btn-default">
          <span><i class="fa fa-camera-retro" style="margin-right: 6px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>Upload Image</span>
          <input type="file" class="upload" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <input class="postall btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" onClick="UserPost()" value="Post">
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Loading User Posts -->
    <div id="mainsectionID">
        <div id="results"><!-- results appear here as list --></div>
    </div>

   <script>
    (function($){   
$.fn.loaddata = function(options) {// Settings
    var settings = $.extend({ 
        loading_gif_url : "images/ajax-loader.gif", //url to loading gif
        end_record_text : 'No more records found!', //no more records to load
        data_url        : 'fetch_pages.php', //url to PHP page
        start_page      : 1 //initial page
    }, options);

    var el = this;  
    loading  = false; 
    end_record = false;
    contents(el, settings); //initial data load

    $(window).scroll(function() { //detact scroll
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()){ //scrolled to bottom of the page
            contents(el, settings); //load content chunk 
        }
    });     
}; 
//Ajax load function
function contents(el, settings){
    var load_img = $('<img/>').attr('src',settings.loading_gif_url).addClass('loading-image'); //create load image
    var record_end_txt = $('<div/>').text(settings.end_record_text).addClass('end-record-info'); //end record text

    if(loading == false && end_record == false){
        loading = true; //set loading flag on
        el.append(load_img); //append loading image
        $.post( settings.data_url, {'page': settings.start_page}, function(data){ //jQuery Ajax post
            if(data.trim().length == 0){ //no more records
                el.append(record_end_txt); //show end record text
                load_img.remove(); //remove loading img
                end_record = true; //set end record flag on
                return; //exit
            }
            loading = false;  //set loading flag off
            load_img.remove(); //remove loading img 
            el.append(data);  //append content 
            settings.start_page ++; //page increment
        })
    }
}

})(jQuery);

$("#results").loaddata(); //load the results into element
    </script>
```

fetch_pages.php code-

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php'; //include config file

$UserID=$_SESSION['uid'];
$UserType=$_SESSION['utype'];

$GLOBALS['lks']=0;
$GLOBALS['cmnts']=0;
$GLOBALS['disabled']="";

//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
exit();
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
?>
<!---post start -->
<?php
//fetch records using page position and item per page. 
$results = $linkID1->query("select slno,posts,img_link,video_link,likes,comments,shares,post_date,post_time,UserID from user_posts where UserID='$UserID' or UserID in(select MyFriendsUserID from user_connections where MyUserID='$UserID') or UserID in(select MyUserID from user_connections where MyFriendsUserID='$UserID') order by slno desc LIMIT $position, $item_per_page")
or

die(mysqli_error());

//output results from database
?>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{ //fetch values
                    $CUID=$row['UserID'];

                    $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select Name,Company,Designation,UserType from user_details where UserID=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $CUID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($Name2,$Company2,$Designation2,$UType);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $stmt->close();

                    $UT2='';
                    if($UType=='A')
                    {
                        $UT2='Advertiser';
                    }
                    else if($UType=='P')
                    {
                        $UT2='Publisher';
                    }

                    $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select ProfilePic from user_picture where UserID=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $CUID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($PPic);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $stmt->close();
        ?>
            <div class="mainsection">
          <div>
            <div class="pull-left postimage"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$PPic ." />"; ?></div>
            <div class="pull-left posttext">
                <div class="postname"><?php echo $Name2; ?></div>
                <p><?php echo $UT2." - ".$Designation2." - ".$Company2; ?></p></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="postdowntxt"><p><?php echo $row['posts']; ?></p></div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="btnclasess" id="likescommentID<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>">
              <div class="likescomment"><?php dataLC($linkID1, $row['slno'],$CUID); ?><a style="padding-right: 7px" href="#"><?php if($GLOBALS['lks']==0){echo '';}else{ echo $GLOBALS['lks']." Likes"; } ?></a><a href="#"><?php if($GLOBALS['cmnts']==0){echo '';}else{ echo $GLOBALS['cmnts']." Comments"; } ?></a></div>
             <div class="pull-left likebtn"><button <?php echo $disabled; ?> class="btn" id="likeButton<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>" onClick="connect(<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Like</button></div>
             <button class="pull-left btnhideshow show_hide" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>"><li class="fa fa-comments show_hide" style="margin-right: 6px;"></li>Comment</button>
             <button class="pull-left btnhideshow show_hide"><li class="fa fa-share-alt show_hide" style="margin-right: 6px;"></li>Share</button>
             <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Display All Comments -->
        <div id="myModal<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>" class="modal">
        <div id="DialogDiv<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content" id="modalDialog<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>">

            <p class="popupheading"><?php if($GLOBALS['cmnts']==0){echo '';}else{ echo $GLOBALS['cmnts']." Comments"; } ?></p> 
            <?php
            $result2 = $linkID1->query("select upc.slno,upc.Comment,upc.CommentedUserID,up.ProfilePic from user_posts_comments upc join user_picture up on upc.CommentedUserID=up.UserID where PostID='$row[slno]' order by upc.slno")
            or
            die(mysqli_error());

            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
            {
        ?>
                <div class="pull-left commnetprofile"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$row2['ProfilePic']." />"; ?></div>
                           <div class="pull-right commentextstyle commentandreply">
                             <?php echo $row2['Comment']; ?>
                           </div>
                           <div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#" onClick="return false;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nReply2<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-reply" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Reply</a></div>
                           <!--<div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Like</a></div>-->
                           <div class="clear"></div>
                           <div id="nReply2<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>" class="collapse">
                    <div>
                     <input class="replybox" type="text" id="nReplyBox2<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>" onkeyup="enter_reply2(<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $CUID; ?>,<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>);">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clear"></div>

                   <!-- Nested Comments Starts -->
                   <div id="NestedCmntsDialog" class="nestedcmnts">
                   <?php
                    $result3 = $linkID1->query("select upcr.slno,upcr.PostID,upcr.ReplyTo,upcr.ReplyBy,upcr.Comments,up.ProfilePic from user_posts_comments_reply upcr join user_picture up on upcr.ReplyBy=up.UserID where upcr.PostID='$row2[slno]' and (upcr.ReplyTo='$row2[CommentedUserID]' or upcr.ReplyBy='$row2[CommentedUserID]') order by upcr.slno")
                    or
                    die(mysqli_error());

                    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
                    {
                 ?>
                   <div class="pull-left commnetprofile"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$row3['ProfilePic']." />"; ?></div>
                   <div class="pull-right commentextstyle commentandreply">
                     <?php echo $row3['Comments']; ?>
                   </div>
                   <div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#" onClick="return false;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nReply2<?php echo ($row3['slno'] * $row3['slno'])+$row3['PostID']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-reply" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Reply</a></div>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
                   <div id="nReply2<?php echo ($row3['slno'] * $row3['slno'])+$row3['PostID']; ?>" class="collapse">
                    <div>
                     <input class="replybox" type="text" id="nReplyBox2<?php echo ($row3['slno'] * $row3['slno'])+$row3['PostID']; ?>" onkeyup="enter_nested_reply2(<?php echo $row3['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $row3['ReplyBy']; ?>,<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $row3['PostID']; ?>);">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <!--<div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Like</a></div>-->
                   <div class="clear"></div>

                 <?php
                    }
                 ?>
                 </div>
                   <!-- Nested Comments Ends -->
        <?php
            }
        ?>
            <div class="invidone"><a href="#" class="close" id="close3">Close</a></div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Display All Comments -->

              <div class="slidingDiv collapse" id="demo<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>">
                <div class="viewallcomments"><a href="#" id="myBtn2" onClick="LoadComment(<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>); return false;">View All Comments</a></div>
                 <div class="allcomment" id="commentsLoad<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>">
                 <?php
                    $result2 = $linkID1->query("select upc.slno,upc.Comment,upc.CommentedUserID,up.ProfilePic from user_posts_comments upc join user_picture up on upc.CommentedUserID=up.UserID where upc.PostID='$row[slno]' order by upc.slno desc limit 3")
                    or
                    die(mysqli_error());

                    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                    {
                 ?>
                 <!-- Showing Top 3 Comments -->
                 <div id="nestedReplyDiv<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>">
                   <div class="pull-left commnetprofile"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$row2['ProfilePic']." />"; ?></div>
                   <div class="pull-right commentextstyle commentandreply">
                     <?php echo $row2['Comment']; ?>
                   </div>
                   <div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#" onClick="return false;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nReply<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-reply" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Reply</a></div>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
                   <div id="nReply<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>" class="collapse">
                    <div>
                     <input class="replybox" type="text" id="nReplyBox<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>" onkeyup="enter_reply(<?php echo $row2['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $CUID; ?>);">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <!--<div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Like</a></div>-->
                   <div class="clear"></div>

                   <!-- Nested Comments Starts -->
                   <div id="NestedCmnts" class="nestedcmnts">
                   <?php
                    $result3 = $linkID1->query("select upcr.slno,upcr.PostID,upcr.ReplyTo,upcr.ReplyBy,upcr.Comments,up.ProfilePic from user_posts_comments_reply upcr join user_picture up on upcr.ReplyBy=up.UserID where upcr.PostID='$row2[slno]' and (upcr.ReplyTo='$row2[CommentedUserID]' or upcr.ReplyBy='$row2[CommentedUserID]') order by upcr.slno")
                    or
                    die(mysqli_error());

                    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
                    {
                 ?>
                   <div class="pull-left commnetprofile"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$row3['ProfilePic']." />"; ?></div>
                   <div class="pull-right commentextstyle commentandreply">
                     <?php echo $row3['Comments']; ?>
                   </div>
                   <div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#" onClick="return false;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nReply<?php echo ($row3['slno'] * $row3['slno'])+$row3['PostID']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-reply" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Reply</a></div>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
                   <div id="nReply<?php echo ($row3['slno'] * $row3['slno'])+$row3['PostID']; ?>" class="collapse">
                    <div>
                     <input class="replybox" type="text" id="nReplyBox<?php echo ($row3['slno'] * $row3['slno'])+$row3['PostID']; ?>" onkeyup="enter_nested_reply(<?php echo $row3['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $row3['ReplyBy']; ?>,<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $row3['PostID']; ?>);">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <!--<div class="pull-left likebtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Like</a></div>-->
                   <div class="clear"></div>

                 <?php
                    }
                 ?>
                 </div>
                   <!-- Nested Comments Ends -->
                 </div>
                 <?php
                    }
                 ?>
                 </div>

                  <textarea id="commentarea<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>" class="secondtextareay pull-left" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Post comments here..." onkeyup="enter_comment(<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $CUID; ?>);"></textarea>
                   <!--<div class="fileUpload second_fileupload btn btn-default pull-left">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-camera-retro" style="margin-right: 6px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="file" class="upload" />
                  </div>-->
                  <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>
             </div>
        <?php
}
?>
<!--post end-->

<?php 
    function dataLC($linkID1, $val, $CUID)
    {
        $UserID=$CUID;
        $LgUserID=$_SESSION['uid'];

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select likes,comments from user_posts where slno=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($lksD,$cmntsD);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $GLOBALS['lks']=$lksD;
        $GLOBALS['cmnts']=$cmntsD;

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select count(slno) from user_posts_likes where MyUserID=? and FrUserID=? and PostID=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $UserID,$UserID,$val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($cnt);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if($cnt>=1)
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="enabled";
        }

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select count(slno) from user_posts_likes where MyUserID=? and FrUserID=? and PostID=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $UserID,$LgUserID,$val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($cnt2);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if($cnt2>=1)
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="enabled";
        }

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select count(slno) from user_posts_likes where MyUserID=? and FrUserID=? and PostID=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $LgUserID,$UserID,$val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($cnt3);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if($cnt3>=1)
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="enabled";
        }
    }
?>

<script>
        $('.btn').on('click', function(e) 
        { 
            $(this).prop('disabled',true); });
    </script>

    <script>
        function UserPost() {
        var x = document.getElementById('posting').value;

        var timezone_offset_minutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        timezone_offset_minutes = timezone_offset_minutes == 0 ? 0 : -timezone_offset_minutes;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user-post.php?p="+x+"&tz="+timezone_offset_minutes,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#mainsectionID").load(" #mainsectionID");
            document.getElementById('posting').value='';
        }
        });
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function connect(num) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user-likes.php?id="+num,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data=='1')
            {
                $("#likescommentID"+num).load(" #likescommentID"+num);
            }
        }
        });
        }

    function enter_comment(postid,userpostedid) {
           if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
               // shift+enter pressed
             }
             else if(event.keyCode == 13){
                      //enter key pressed
                      var cmnt = document.getElementById('commentarea'+postid).value;
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "user-comments.php?id="+postid+"&cmnt="+cmnt,
                        success: function(data2) {
                            if(data2=='1')
                            {
                                $("#commentsLoad"+postid).load(" #commentsLoad"+postid);
                                $("#likescommentID"+postid).load(" #likescommentID"+postid);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                      document.getElementById('commentarea'+postid).value='';
            }
            else{
                //nothing
            }
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function enter_reply(slno,userpostedid) {
           if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
               // shift+enter pressed
             }
             else if(event.keyCode == 13){
                      //enter key pressed
                      var cmnt = document.getElementById('nReplyBox'+slno).value;
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "user-comments-reply.php?id="+slno+"&cmnt="+cmnt,
                        success: function(data2) {
                            if(data2=='1')
                            {
                                $("#commentsLoad"+slno).load(" #commentsLoad"+slno);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                      document.getElementById('nReplyBox'+slno).value='';
            }
            else{
                //nothing
            }
    }


    function enter_reply2(slno,userpostedid,dno) {
           if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
               // shift+enter pressed
             }
             else if(event.keyCode == 13){
                      //enter key pressed
                      var cmnt = document.getElementById('nReplyBox2'+slno).value;
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "user-comments-reply.php?id="+slno+"&cmnt="+cmnt,
                        success: function(data2) {
                            if(data2=='1')
                            {

                                $("#DialogDiv"+dno).load(" #DialogDiv"+dno);
                                //$("#modalDialog"+dno).load(" #modalDialog"+dno);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                      document.getElementById('nReplyBox2'+slno).value='';
            }
            else{
                //nothing
            }
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function enter_nested_reply(slno,userpostedid,divNo,pid) {
           if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
               // shift+enter pressed
             }
             else if(event.keyCode == 13){
                      //enter key pressed
                      var tot=(slno*slno)+pid;
                      var cmnt = document.getElementById('nReplyBox'+tot).value;

                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "user-comments-reply-nested.php?id="+slno+"&cmnt="+cmnt+"&upid="+userpostedid,
                        success: function(data2) {
                            if(data2=='1')
                            {
                                $("#nestedReplyDiv"+divNo).load(" #nestedReplyDiv"+divNo);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                      document.getElementById('nReplyBox'+tot).value='';
            }
            else{
                //nothing
            }
    }


    function enter_nested_reply2(slno,userpostedid,divNo,pid) {
           if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
               // shift+enter pressed
             }
             else if(event.keyCode == 13){
                      //enter key pressed
                      var tot=(slno*slno)+pid;
                      var cmnt = document.getElementById('nReplyBox2'+tot).value;

                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "user-comments-reply-nested.php?id="+slno+"&cmnt="+cmnt+"&upid="+userpostedid,
                        success: function(data2) {
                            if(data2=='1')
                            {
                                $("#DialogDiv"+divNo).load(" #DialogDiv"+divNo);
                                //$("#modalDialog"+divNo).load(" #modalDialog"+divNo);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                      document.getElementById('nReplyBox2'+tot).value='';
            }
            else{
                //nothing
            }
    }
    </script>

    <script>

    function LoadComment(num) {
        var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal'+num);
        var span2 = document.getElementById("close3");

        span2.onclick = function() {
                modal2.style.display = "none";
            }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal2) {
                    modal2.style.display = "none";
                }
            }

        var x = document.getElementById('myBtn2');
        modal2.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Called the pagination again in the success method of ajax.